# How to display the page title of the destination page of a short url in mouseover text?

Tags: javascript, mouseover, onmouseover, url-shortener

Not simply the long url, but the pagetitle for the destination page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use title attribute

```
<a title="page title" href="../fdf/page">Go</a>
```

Comment: Jayantha, you have a type-o. Not titile, but title

    **<a title="page title" href="..\fdf\page">Go</a>**

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like that (jQuery dummy code):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var page = $.get($(this).attr('href'));
        var title = page.match('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/');
        $(this).attr('title', title);
    })
})
```

... feel free to edit and fix this solution...